# Ricoh printer fail to scan to a folder

Tags: active-directory, samba, printers

I have a ricoh printer / scanner over my network and i need to scan to a folder.

My server have a folder named "public" and the public ip is "10.0.0.254".

I have a SAMBA4 AD as a controller. I have created one user called "scanner" whit password "scanner" and have set permissions to this folder.

My printer cant connect to SAMBA and show me error on authentication.

In other hosts of my network i can access / write the folder.

help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you answered it yourself.
Answer: it is a domain controller and you log in without permissions.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question. I will write it clearly so that everyone can understand, including who takes a little longer to understand. The login and password are correct, how do I login with this printer on my AD on samba4? With this same configuration I can login to SAMBA PDC.

Comment: have you tried to ask samba authors a question or report a problem by sending logs from Linux https://bugzilla.samba.org/

Comment: Off course not, this problems are related to the printer or misconfiguration, is not a samba bug.